# Accessing struts action methods from JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I'm having a problem accessing methods from my struts 2 action in the returned JSP. From what I understand, if I have an action that looks like this:

```
public class HomeAction {
    public String execute() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return "somethh";
    }
}
```

Then from the JSP I should be able to call `${something}` and get `"somethh"` returned. This doesn't seem to work properly however. Is there any obvious configuration that I might have missed for this? I'm using struts 2, spring 3.1, and tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, since what you have asked is quite abstract and its always better to show your JSP page where you are trying o do the things what you have described which can given better picture to the other.

You need to tell S2 about which method you want it to call, in case of you have not defined any method default is `execute()`.

in your case you can tell S2 which method you want to call either by using configuration file (struts.xml ) or by annotation like

```
<action name="default" class="tutorial.HomeAction">
  <result>Welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="somethh" class="tutorial.HomeAction" method=getSomethh>
  <result>Welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

here you have to configure the action name different like `<s:url value="default.action"/> and <s:url value="somethh.action"/>`

If you want same Action name but want to redirect to different method of your action class you can configure the method name in your `<s:url>` also like

```
<s:url value="generic.action" method="getSomethh">
```

in the above example you have told S2 through tags which method of your action class you want to call and all you need to configure them in your struts.xml file

Comment: I was trying to access a method directly from struts in it's returned jsp. Turns out I had managed to screw up my environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an environmental issue was causing struts to act strangely. It was working as I expected it should, apologies for the vague question.

Comment: Consider editing your question to mention this, or answer with the exact change you made and accept your answer if you think this could affect other persons. Have other answers helped? If so, then consider upvoting them.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly call the method from jsp file.if you do so then why mvc.Struts2 is a very easy framework.You can configure the method and class strutsconfig.xml. and map it with an action.
the instance variables can be accessed directly in jsp.For example if you have a method

```
    public class ABCAction extends ActionSupport{
    public String getNames(){

    nameslist=dao.getNamelist();
    retrun "success";
    }
    //getters and setters for namelist
    public setNamesList(List nameslist){
    this.nameslist-namelist;

}
}
public List getNames(){
return this.nameslist;
}
}
```

you can access nameslist in your jsp directly--

Comment: You can call a method directly from the jsp! I've just fixed the environment problem and now it's working as I'd expected it would. Thanks anyway!